# Making a Acey Ducey game in Python

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to use the class library that I made to create an interactive game called [Acey Duecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acey_Deucey_(card_game))

The criteria is that I have the player get two cards, make an amount to wager, and then get the third card and a decision whether they have won or lost.

I have created a card Library called `cardLib` and here is the code. I have tested the code and everything seems to be working. The code below `cardLib` is called `cardMain` which is the game. When I run `p1.deal`, I get the whole card, but I just want the number of the card. How do I make that and compare the two cards with the dealer?

cardLib.py:

```
import random

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, num, suit):
        self.num = num
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s%s' % (self.num,
                             self.suit)

    def __repr__(self): return str(self)

    return int(num)

class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']

    def deal(self):
        topCard = self.deck.pop(0)
        print(topCard)

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def Order(self):
        self.deck.sort()
```

cardMain:

```
import cardLib
#starting cash
cash = 100
while cash > 0:
    p1 = cardLib.Deck()
    #shuffle the card
    p1.shuffle()
    #generate 2 cards for player
    pCard1 = p1.deal()
    pCard2 = p1.deal()
    #generate 1 card for dealer
    dealer = p1.deal()
    print("The dealer card is",dealer)
    print("You have an amount of",cash)
    wager = int(input("How much are you willing to wage? "))
    #sort the cards

    print("Your card is", low, "and", high)
    if dealer > low and dealer < high:
        cash += wager
        print("You won!")
        print("You now have",cash)
    else:
        cash -= wager
        print("You lost")
        print("You now have",cash)
print("Game over!")
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I added the question

Comment: `deal` should `return` not `print`

Comment: there's an unrelated error in cardLib.py, which is that you use the random library without importing it

Comment: I have changed deal to return and not print

Comment: I added import random up the top. Sorry

Comment: @quadratini7 Just change the function `deal` to: `return topCard.num`.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running your code, it seems to run into this exception: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'` on `if pCard1 < pCard2:`. However, `Deck.deal()` doesn't return anything as @Nick A said. This can be fixed by changing `print(topCard)` to `return(topCard)` in `cardLib.py`.

Another unrelated problem is that 
in your `Deck` class, the `shuffle` function tries to use `random.shuffle`. However, since this module hasn't been imported, it results in an exception. So, just add `import random` at the top.

Also, if the code hadn't been messed up while copy pasted, they're a few places where indentation is messed up. So, you might want to fix that.

Also, if you're interested in obtaining the number of the card when using deal, you could either change `return(topCard)` to `return(topCard.num)` or you could do `p1.deal()` instead.

Comment: I have took @Nick A's advice and changed to return instead of print. Program seems to work better now. I have updated the code above once again. import random was in the code but copy paste was messed up. Sorry about that!! also fixed indentation.

Comment: Are there any other problems?

Comment: When I run p1.deal on cardMain(), I get the whole card but I just the number of the card

Comment: @quadratini7 Could you clarify please?

Comment: @quadratini7 I think I fixed your problem.

Comment: Adding to problems: `num_rank` returns an int while `self.num` is a string